# How to use code from terraform sibling directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to use specific code from sibling directories and I am having some trouble doing so. As an example, please see below for how my files are structured:

```
parents/
    brother/
        main.tf
        outputs.tf
        variables.tf
    sister/
        main.tf
        outputs.tf
        variables.tf
```

I want to use a definition that I created in `brother/main.tf` in `sister/main.tf` and I can't seem to figure out the right way to do so. I have tried to use modules:

```
module "brother" {
    source = "../brother"
}
```

Doing this works, but it doesn't. I am able to import and use the code, but for some reason terraform is creating a bunch of other resources with a new resource name, using the new module name (if that makes any sense). Essentially, it creates the desired resource, but also created 100+ other unwanted.

I can easily get this to work by putting the definition I want to use in the same `sister` directory, but that is not how I want to structure my files. What is the right way to do this? If I have an IAM role that is defined in `brother`, and I want to reference it in `sister`, how can I do that? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Current Code:

sister/main.tf

```
resource "aws_config_config_rule" "test-rule" {
  name = "test-rule"

  source {
    owner             = "AWS"
    source_identifier = "TEST"
  }

  depends_on = ["aws_config_configuration_recorder.config_configuration_recorder"]
}

resource "aws_config_configuration_recorder" "config_configuration_recorder" {
  name     = "config_configuration_recorder"
  role_arn = "${var.test_assume_role_arn}"
}
```

brother/main.tf

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "test_assume_role" {
    name               = "${var.test_assume_role_name}"
    path               = "/"
    assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "config.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

So basically, I want to be able to use the `test_assume_role` arn in the `sister/main.tf`.

Comment: Can you also show the code in `brother` and `sister` modules (or an MCVE of them)? And more clearly show what you want to happen and what is currently happening with the code you have

Comment: Sure @ydaetskcoR, please see my edits for, hopefully, a clearer explanation

Answer (score 6):

When you require another module it will recreate those resources.
It sounds like you want to reference the state of the already created resources. You can do this using [remote state data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html).

This allows you to read outputs of another state but doesn't create additional resources

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "brother" {
  backend = "..."
}

resource "aws_instance" "sister" {
  # ...
  subnet_id = "${data.terraform_remote_state.brother.my_output}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes complete sense..and yes that is what I do, but currently our setup is not using remote states (although the plan is to get there). Is this only possible with remote states?

Comment: You can import a statefile that uses a local backend, you just need to configure it https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/local.html

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to outputting an attribute of a resource to the Terraform state and reading it in with the `terraform_remote_state` data source would be to just use the appropriate data source for your resource in the first place where possible.

In this case you can use the [`aws_iam_role` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/iam_role.html) to look up the ARN for an IAM role by its name:

```
data "aws_iam_role" "example" {
  name = "an_example_role_name"
}
```