# how can i get a subsequent terraform deployment to use a vpc created in sibling module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to understand how to have the following terraform project structure allow me to stand up a vpc that can then be used in subsequent `apply` operations in sibling directories.  For example,

```
├── dev
│   ├── main.tf
├── test
│   ├── main.tf
├── shared
│   ├── outputs.tf
│   ├── variables.tf
│   └── main.tf
```

In `shared/main.tf` I define

```
module "vpc" {
  source               = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version              = "2.77.0"
  name                 = "vpc"
  cidr                 = "10.0.0.0/16"
  azs                  = ["us-west-2a"]
}
```

And in `dev/main.tf` I define (among other things)

```
module "shared" {
  source = "../shared"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "dev-subnet-pub" {
  vpc_id      = module.shared.vpc_id
  cidr_block  = "10.0.1.0/28"
  tags = {
    Name        = "dev-subnet-pub"
    Terraform   = "true"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

Both deployments are successful, but if I `terraform apply` in `/shared` and then again in `/dev` I end up with 2 VPCs with the same CIDR, but the most recently created one has the rest of my `/dev` resources in it.  Expected behavior is that the resources from `/dev` are deployed into the VPC created from the first `terraform apply` (ie, I want to do this in `/prod` and `/test` sibling directories as well).

Must I use terraform workspaces?

Answer (score 1):

This solution ended up working for my purposes.

After you `terraform apply` in `/shared`, in `dev/main.tf` define

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "vpc" {
  backend = "local"
    config = {
    path = "../shared/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "dev-subnet-pub" {
  vpc_id      = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.vpc_id
  cidr_block  = "10.0.1.0/28"
  tags = {
    Name        = "dev-subnet-pub"
    Terraform   = "true"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

NOTE: There are a few variations on this question, notably [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748606/2780360) that makes reference to [local backends](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/local.html).

I'm going to answer my own question and leave it to someone else to tell me if it's too similar, but I think the environment/account context is distinct.  Also important to note here a caveat for local backend solutions to this question:

> We do not recommend using these options in new systems, even if you
> are running Terraform in automation. Instead, [select a different
> backend which supports remote state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/) and configure it within your root
> module, which ensures that everyone working on your configuration will
> automatically retrieve and store state in the correct shared location
> without any special command line options.

Additionally, [S3 seems to be a commonly used backend solution](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html#multi-account-aws-architecture).

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution is to deploy your setup in two stages. First you deploy the `shared` which creates the VPC. Then you pass the `VPCid` into `/dev` as an input variable during `terraform apply`. The variable can have a default value of `null`, and if the `VPCid` is not provided, then the `/dev` creates its own VPC.

Same goes for `/prod` or any other type of environment you want to create.

Comment: if I don't want to manually supply the VPCid (ie, everything should use the shared VPC resource, and leave it to the dev and test envs to define their own subnets within the VPC) am I left with tracking state in some form of backend?

Comment: @d8aninja You have to know something about the VPC. such as cidr or name. If your `/shared` creates VPC with some known properties, your `dev` and `prod` would then use [aws_vpc data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/vpc) to search for it and get its `VPCId`. This way you don't have to pass anything manually.

Comment: see my recent update; this seems to have worked in my case

Comment: @d8aninja That's good it worked.